# Faithfully flat descent and finite map

Tags: algebraic-geometry, flatness, etale-cohomology

Let $X,Y,Z$ schemes with $f:X \to Y$ and $g:Z \to Y$ with $f$ faithfully flat. I'd like to prove that if $g_Y:X \times_{Y} Z \to X$ is a finite map , so it is $g$.

The part I'm having trouble with is showing that the map is affine: given that, proving that it is finite should be easier using faithfully flatness. I'm trying to use faithfully flat descent but I do not really do how to deal with this.

Comment: I don't remember what the canonical proof for affineness being flat local is, but it seems to me that you can probably deduce the result by using flat base change and Serre's affineness criterion. You can probably also just use descent for qcoh to construct the qcoh algebra it's relative spec of.

Comment: Only problem with using flat base change is that it requires that $f$ should be quasi separated and quasi compact

Comment: You can work affine locally, no?

Comment: Sorri I did not get this last part